# Why is my button clicked event being called 4 times?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Probably a noob question, but I'm trying to write a simple iPhone app that increments a label by the number of times a button is clicked.  I have the following code:

```
#import "Controller.h"

int *i = 0;
@implementation Controller 
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {      
    NSString *numTimesClicked = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i++    ];      
    myLabel.text    = numTimesClicked;      
}
@end
```

When I click the button, the label updates in multiples of 4 (4,8,12,16, etc).  What might I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look at the definition of `i`:

```
int *i = 0;
```

`i` isn't an integer — it's a *pointer to* an integer. The size of an int is 4 bytes on your architecture, so the pointer increments by 4 (which would be the address of the next int in an array of ints). You want to declare it as just `int i = 0`.

Comment: +1 and marked as answered.  Thanks for the help... I'm coming from a c# background and I'm still getting my head around when to label something as a point and when not to.